# WPF close window on validation fail at window load

Tags: wpf, initialization

Can we close WPF window after `InitializeComponent()` if any validation fails? I am validating that the file exist on window load, if the file doesn't exist, then how to close the window before it loads?

Comment: Do you really just want to close the window or the full application?

Comment: @jens: just want to close window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a different approach.

I think this should not be decided by the window itself, but rather by some business rules validation object.

With WPF it comes natural to using the MVVM pattern so the validation might be done the the ViewModel or a dedication validation class. The should make the decision if a window should be opened at all.

This approach would spare from instancing, opening, and eventually closing a completely unneeded window if the opening condiotions are not met.

Comment: jens can you provide any sample for this

Comment: To make this answer "design independent": in short, validate that the file exists *before* opening the window.  If the file does not exist, simply do not open the window.

Answer (score 0):

It looks better use MVVM and do your validation in ViewModel before showing window. If validation in viewModel is OK, then show window and if validation has some errors dont show window. Using InitializeComponent() is too late to determine opening and closing window.